# achieve iOS Whatsapp UI in android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

iOS Whatsapp brings long pressed recyclerview item to center (near to the original item position)  and blurs background
as shown in the gif below
https://drive.google.com/file/d/166H0YvI8ZCaSyrV4FLugEk5_HlCjWG-1/view?usp=sharing

How can we achieve this in android?

Comment: Hint: Use a zoom based animation, use the animation listener & blur/unblur the background via framework / 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. We can do the same UI in android.

Comment: The question is how?

Comment: Can you tell me what approach to take?

Comment: just start with material design.